# python open new window

Tags: python, tkinter

idk what to do when i define a function it dosent wanna use it in a button command
NameError: name 'openNewWindow' is not defined. Did you mean: 'PanedWindow'
idk whats the problem

```
from tkinter import*


win = Tk()

win.title("igra")
win.config(bg = "black")
win.overrideredirect(True)
win.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(win.winfo_screenwidth(), win.winfo_screenheight()))
pitanje = Label(win, text = "dali ste sami?", bg="black", fg="white", font= ('Open Sans', 50)).place(x= "570", y= "300")
odgovor = Button(win, text = "da", bg="black", fg="white", font= ('Open Sans', 50), borderwidth=0)
odgovor.place(x= "560", y= "480")
odgovor2 = Button(win, text = "ne", bg="black", fg="white", font= ('Open Sans', 50), borderwidth=0,command=openNewWin)
odgovor2.place(x= "840", y= "480")

def openNewWin():
    openNewWin = Toplevel(win)
    openNewWin.geometry("720x720")




win.mainloop()
```

Comment: `openNewWin` is not defined at the point in the code where you are trying to use it. I suggest moving the definition before `win = Tk()`.

Comment: `openNewWin` *isn't defined yet* at the point where you're creating the Button.  Move the function definition up, by at least a few lines, so that it is before the point of use.

Comment: thank you so much the more you know but know when it opens the window it isint fullscreen it has a title tk but i want it fullscreen

Comment: my original window is fullscreen

Comment: nothing i found thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you want? I rearranged code. I moved function before widgets.

Try this:

```
from tkinter import*


win = Tk()

win.title("igra")
win.config(bg = "black")
#win.overrideredirect(True)
win.geometry("1080x900")


def openNewWin():
    openNewWin = Toplevel(win)
    openNewWin.geometry("720x720")


pitanje = Label(win, text = "dali ste sami?", bg="black", fg="white", font= ('Open Sans', 50)).place(x= "570", y= "300")
odgovor = Button(win, text = "da", bg="black", fg="white", font= ('Open Sans', 50), borderwidth=0)
odgovor.place(x= "560", y= "480")
odgovor2 = Button(win, text = "ne", bg="black", fg="white", font= ('Open Sans', 50), borderwidth=0,command=openNewWin)
odgovor2.place(x= "840", y= "480")

win.mainloop()
```

Result main window:

[image]

Result for `Toplevel`:

[image]